# sticky sidebar height is larger than the screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, css-grid

When the screen size is smaller, the rest of the side bar content is invisible (like overflow: hidden) in my project. But it in example it is scrollable, even though it is scrollable it is stretching 1.cms-element, if I make `align-items: flex-start;` it is only affecting 1.cms-element and making huge gap between 3.cms-element.
If I give `overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 100vh;'` to `.side` class it is effecting sidebar height and style. If I give `min-height: 100vh;` to `.side` class it working but stretching another elements to fit in the content.

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-grmxny?file=style.scss)

***How can I achieve this without effecting another elements ? Also order should not change as given 1, 2, 3, 4.***

How can I make sidebar visible in all sizes without effecting other elements size

[image: This is how looks like on the project]

Comment: It's a little unclear what you want to achieve, could you try explaining again?

Comment: as shown in image and stackblitz, when sticky sidebar height is larger than the screen size it is not visible or even if it is visible it is stretching another elements on the left, I want to make sticky navbar visible when screen size is small without stretching another elements on the left.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to wrap the content inside the sidebar in a container with a fixed height and overflow-y: scroll; This way, the container will be scrollable while not affecting the rest of the page elements.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="side">
  <div class="side-content">
    <div class="cms-element">1. CMS Element</div>
    <div class="cms-element">2. CMS Element</div>
    <div class="cms-element">3. CMS Element</div>
    <div class="cms-element">4. CMS Element</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.side {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.side-content {
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the sidebar fit in all screen sizes, it is necessary to adjust the gap of each element with respect to the sidebar height (`calc(100vh - ([no. of .cms-element] * 2rem)`), as the `row-gap` value can interfere with the sidebar height.

Also by using `grid-row: ([total no. of .cms-element]+1)/-2` in the `.side` element, it is possible to preserve the gap between the 1.cms-element and 3.cms-element.

JavaScript can be utilized for a more flexible approach to maintaining the value mentioned above.

Here is the solution based on your example:

**SCSS:**

```
.cms-frame {
  .frame-body {
    display: grid;
    gap: 2rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));

    .cms-element {grid-column: span 12 / span 12;} // for small devices make it full width

    @include desktop() {     

      > *:not(.side) {
        grid-column: span 8 / span 8;
      }
      
      .side {
        height: calc(100vh - (3 * 2rem)); // reduce gap from each .cms-element excluding .side
        overflow: auto;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0rem;
        grid-row: 4/-2; // since .side position is at 2 make its end-position -2 and start position total element
        grid-column-start: 9;
        grid-column-end: 13;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
const cmsEl = document.querySelectorAll('.cms-element');
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.side');

sidebar.setAttribute('style', `
height: calc(100vh - (${cmsEl.length - 1} * 2rem));
grid-row: ${cmsEl.length }/-2;
`); // -1 to excude .side itself
```

Hope you find it useful :)